# How to get full Lucene index in RAM?

Tags: java, lucene

I am designing a system where we have a very high efficiency requirements. To achieve that I am planning to have entire lucene index in RAM. Our Index size would be around 5-6 GB. Now [`RAMDirectory`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/store/RAMDirectory.html) does not work well with larger indexes and [`MMapDirectory`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/store/MMapDirectory.html) does not load entire index into the RAM.

Do we have any method by which I can make `MMapDirectory` loading entire index proactively? If not, do we have any other ways to achieve the goal?

P.S. I have gone through [`MemoryIndex`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_4_0/memory/org/apache/lucene/index/memory/MemoryIndex.html) but that does not replicate the Lucene indexes in memory. Each instance can hold at most one Lucene "document". Whereas we want a full lucene indexing capability but entire index in RAM.

Comment: What about a RAM disk?